# How to set the html id for an element inside a user control for 2 instances on a page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, master-pages, asp.net-2.0

I'm new to the land of asp.net, I've searched and read up but have had no luck with this.

I have a standard unordered nested list which I'm using for the main horizontal navigation of my site, I am also using the same nested list as a vertical navigation in the left column of the website, which I animate as a tree style nav.

For simple maintenance I'd like to have one user control containing the nested nav list and add that twice to the page.

The site is using masterpages. In a master page I can call the user control twice to occur in the header and in the sidebar, but I need to be able to set the html id individually for each one of these instances of the nav UL so I can target them with js.

I am constrained to using in-line asp.net as I currently no access to code behind.

I was hoping to be able to include an attribute like maybe clientID in the masterpage
 e.g. :

```
<uc3:mainnav id="mainnav" clientID="main-nav" runat="server"></uc3:mainnav>
<uc3:mainnav id="sidebarnav" clientID="sidebar-nav" runat="server"></uc3:mainnav>
```

or alternatively is it possible to put some other attribute/value in these lines in a masterpage which could then be read by the user control and set the id of highest ul element in the control.

As previously mentioned I'm constrained by external parties to doing this with asp.net 2.0  inline and can't do this with code behind.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property to the UserControl that specifies anything you want. This property name and value can then be specified in the markup for the declaration of the control just as with any other control.

Comment: OP stated that he had to do it inline, as he has no access to the code-behind.  I would assume this also means he has no access to the code of the user control.

Comment: hi, I can write inline code within the usercontrol just not codebehind for the control.  so would this mean I could do something like this:

Comment: `<uc3:mainnav id="mainnav" myid="somevalue" runat="server"></uc3:mainnav>`  then in the control itself I could have `<ul id="<% myid %>">` sorry I'm quite new to asp.net

Comment: this doesn't work for me so I'm doing something wrong, I just don't know how to access the attribute value from inside the user control.

Comment: @PeterBromberg could you me give a simple code example for inline access of user control attributes from within the user control?